# PHP Xpath return zero match

Tags: php, xpath

Considering this XML

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd" ID="_a75adf55-01d7-40cc-929f-dbd8372ebdfc" IssueInstant="2009-09-09T00:46:02Z" Version="2.0">
   <Subject>
      <NameID>801234567890</NameID>
   </Subject>
    ....
</Assertion>`

PHP

`$dom = new DOMDocument();
$ret = $dom->loadXML($data);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node_list = $xp->query('/Assertion');`

`$node_list->length` return 0 element. I want to extract the DOMElement but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: Assuming it's properly done implementation there is a need to specify namespaces when looking for elements

Comment: What kind of namespace? Can you answer by giving an exemple? Can I put a random namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the comments by Sami Kuhmonen you may need to register the namespaces, here is an example:

```
<?php
$string= <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd" ID="_a75adf55-01d7-40cc-929f-dbd8372ebdfc" IssueInstant="2009-09-09T00:46:02Z" Version="2.0">
   <Subject>
      <NameID>801234567890</NameID>
   </Subject>
</Assertion>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($string);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

// registering the namespaces
$xp->registerNamespace('a','urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion');
$xp->registerNamespace('b','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

// using the prefix of the registered namespace in the xpath expression
$node_list = $xp->query('/a:Assertion');

print $node_list->length
?>
```